# How can I speed up my LSTM DQN training time?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, dqn

I tried implementing my own DQN with LSTM model and the problem is that it's taking too long to run. For instance, running 2 episodes takes 10 mins, and each episode only has around 1.2k time steps (financial time series). I'm not sure if there are better ways to implement the model to speed up training time, or if I'm just limited by processing power.

I run my Python script on Google Colab and switching the hardware accelerator to GPU/TPU didn't help either.

I know there are RL libraries out there, but some of them don't support RNN, and I find the documentations for creating a custom policy model to be very confusing. That's why I decided to code out the DQN agent instead of relying on existing libraries. I get to understand more in-depth as well since I'm new to Machine Learning.

Here's the code for the LSTM model:

```
learning_rate = 0.0001
no_of_features = 9
lookback_window = 60

def create_DL_model():
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(LSTM(64,input_shape= (no_of_features,lookback_window),return_sequences=True)) #return_sequences =True if its followed by another Recurrent layer
  model.add(LeakyReLU())
  model.add(LSTM(32))
  model.add(LeakyReLU())
  model.add(Dense(no_of_actions))
  model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer = Adam(learning_rate = learning_rate))
  return model

#initialise main network and target network with the same weights
main_net = create_DL_model()
target_net = create_DL_model()
target_net.set_weights(tmain_net.get_weights())
```

and the code for DQN agent:

```
discount = 0.3
replay_size = 5000
min_replay_size= 100
network_update_steps = 1000
no_of_episodes = 10
batch_size = 64

epsilon = 1.0  # Epsilon greedy parameter
epsilon_min = 0.01  # Minimum epsilon greedy parameter
epsilon_max = 1.0  # Maximum epsilon greedy parameter
epsilon_interval = epsilon_max - epsilon_min

epsilon_greedy_frames = 150000 

replay_memory = deque(maxlen= replay_size)
timesteps = 0
episode_reward_list =[]
episode_counter = 0

#for loop for episodes
for i in range(2): 
  episode_counter+=1
  
  episode_reward = 0
  state = np.array(train_env.reset()) #state has shape (1,9,60)

  #flag for end of episode 
  done = False
  
  #while loop to run through df per episode 
  while not done:
    timesteps+=1

    #exploration
    if epsilon> np.random.random() or len(replay_memory) < min_replay_size:
      #take random action 
      action = np.random.choice(no_of_actions)
    else:
      #select action with max expected future reward
      action = np.argmax(main_net.predict(state)[0])
    
    #Epsilon decay 
    epsilon -= epsilon_interval / epsilon_greedy_frames
    epsilon = max(epsilon, epsilon_min)

    next_state,reward,done,info = train_env.step([action]) #'action' must be iterable
    next_state = np.array(next_state)

    #update reward
    episode_reward += reward

    #add transition into replay memory
    replay_memory.append((state,action,reward,next_state,done))

    #update state and step. 
    state=next_state

    #Train the model only if there are sufficient transitions in replay memory
    if len(replay_memory) < min_replay_size:
      continue
    else:
      batch = random.sample(replay_memory,batch_size)
      
      #current states
      train_states = np.array([transition[0][0] for transition in batch])
      Q_list = main_net.predict(train_states)
      
      #future states
      train_future_states = np.array([transition[3][0] for transition in batch])
      future_Q_list = target_net.predict(train_future_states)

      #for model training 
      X = []
      y= []

      for index, (state,action,reward,next_state,done_) in enumerate(batch):
        
        if not done_:
          max_future_q = np.max(future_Q_list[index])
          new_q = reward + discount*max_future_q
        #last step no more future reward
        else:
          new_q = reward

        #update the 'correct' Q value from target network
        curr_Q = Q_list[index]
        curr_Q[action] = new_q

        #append to training data
        X.append(state[0])
        y.append(curr_Q)

      with tensorflow.device('/gpu:0'):
        #model fit training data to update the weights based on loss
        main_net.fit(np.array(X),np.array(y),batch_size = batch_size,verbose=0)

      #update target network every 1000 timesteps
      if timesteps % network_update_steps ==0:
        print(timesteps)
        print(epsilon)
        target_net.set_weights(main_net.get_weights())
  
  #update episode reward
  episode_reward_list.append(episode_reward)
  print('Episode #{}: Reward{}'.format(episode_counter,episode_reward))
```

Comment: Training is usually slow. How much more performance do you want? There are some tricks you can try, such as using tf.data to load data or training with mixed precision or maybe some GPU tricks. You can also use the tensorboard profiler to identify bottlenecks. Another suggestion would be to look for optimised models in academic papers. Maybe something like normalisation could help as well.

Comment: @Majitsima At this rate, I'd need about 17 days to train a model on 50 financial assets for 100k time steps each. It's kind of ridiculous. I tried a vanilla DQN using stable baseline with their MLP policy, it only took a few minutes to run 100k time steps per asset. Im aware that LSTM takes a longer time to train, but this difference is HUGE! Thanks for your recommendations anyway. PS: The reason for using LSTM is because Im trying to replicate a research paper